# Can an employer interpret an email with the intention to move on as resignation?

Tags: job-change, australia

I sent my employer the email 3 weeks ago which contained my intention to "secure employment with XXX (another company)". At the time my boss was trying to secure work for me in another city, however I had learnt in the meantime that only company XXX would be able win the contracting work, hence I sent the email. My boss has now retrospectively interpreted my email as notice of resignation, and has provided final pay details.

In his reply to my email and in subsequent conversations, my email was never before interpreted as a resignation letter until I received the final pay details yesterday.

Can I instead give my notice of resignation now, and propose a new end date in the future?

Comment: So you told your current boss that you were going to try get a job at a competitor and you didn't think anything could go wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you should consult a lawyer - but on the face of it, your position does seem very weak. I am not an Australian lawyer, but perhaps legally you haven't resigned - so they technically are firing you - and that could mean something. Regardless, your current situation seems entirely self-inflicted.

If it is a genuine misunderstanding, you should attempt to clear it up **immediately**, as not clearing it up would probably be considered tacit acceptance of their interpretation.

But even if you convince them that they have over-interpreted your statement, why should your current employer keep you? What would be the benefit to them? You have made it clear that you wish to move on, so from now on you are probably a financial liability rather than an asset.

Your situation brilliantly illustrates why one **never ever** discloses such intentions to an employer. Only when a new job has been secured should one formally resign. There is no gray area; you should appear 100% employed at your current job until you resign.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have received a contract from company XXX, so my position is ok. However because they have retrospectively interpreted the date I sent my email as my resignation date, they only have to pay me for 4 weeks from that date rather than when I want to put in my actual resignation.

Comment: Ah OK - so the problem is that you didn't explicitly state a resignation date - so they assumed it was the email date. Again - you could try to clear it up - but perhaps the wheels have already been set in motion.